# Is there a module that provides perpetual results on scroll?

Tags: 7, views, ajax

Let's say you have a page that is a view, and the view is set to page at 50 items. You have 150 items, so you have three pages. Is there a module that will load additional results, like 30 more, when the user scrolls towards the bottom?

The effect is that you don't need to use the pager, as new results appear automatically.
The effect I want to get is the one used in [this site](http://sortfolio.com/).

Is there a module that will do this for a view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. There are two (quotes included are from their project pages):

- [Views Infinite Scroll](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) (Requires Views 3):

  > ... provides pluggable pagers that enables Views infinite scrolling (autopaging, depaging, endless pages ... you name it) by using jquery.autopager plugin. Using this module with views page display will load another page whenever the user reaches bottom of the page.
- [Views Infinite Pager](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_pager):

  > ... implements "infinite pager" (earlier called "sliding pager") functionality for Views. Infinite pagers open the next page via Ajax below the current page, each sub-page expanding the page vertically downwards. For a well-known infinite pager example, visit a stream on Twitter.com.

Comment: awesome, please mark the question as solved! :)

Comment: I would suggest that you also explain which one of those you end up using and why, that would be very helpful if someone else lands here with the same question.